# Validate if a string contains both English and Devanagari letters

Tags: android, regex, string, android-studio, flutter

The only allowed one format English or Devanagari.

Example:

```
string="abhijit अभिजित"
```

How to check combination of English and Devanagari letters with the help of regex pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long time i have added my own regex pattern and my problem is solved

Please try this solution ...

Definitely save your valuable time

```
//here check combination of English and Devanagari letters

static String namePattern = "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\u0900-\u097F])";

//Pass your name in this method

static bool isNameValid(String name) {
  if (name.isEmpty) {
    return false;
  } else {
    RegExp nameExp = RegExp(Regex.namePattern , caseSensitive: false, multiLine: false);
    return nameExp.hasMatch(input.trim());
  }
}
```